# How can you create and manage multiple RSS feeds/ xml files for podcast subscribers?

Tags: xml, database, rss, bulkinsert, podcast

I would love for any guidance on tool or code that could accomplish this:

**GOAL**: We have 200+ paid members who each need a unique RSS feed for our paid podcast episodes. These can then be used by the individual member to feed into their preferred podcast player. The idea is if the feeds are unique, the feeds can be created or removed based on if the member cancels their subscription. There are paid options to accomplish this, but I know there's gotta be a way to do this.

**How it Works**: It seems like there should be some tool, (maybe a database tool?) that would allow me to have one master file (the RSS xml file for the podcast) in which I could insert the xml data for a new episode, that would then update all the dependent or child RSS files (unique for each member). So, when a new episode is published, we update one file, or even do a search replace across a couple hundred xml files to add the new lines of code for the new episode in the RSS xml files.

**Question**: Does anyone know of a tool where I could bulk create/edit many RSS/XML files to accomplish this? Maybe some database tool like PHPmyAdmin could accomplish this? I'm a web guy, but mostly work with frontend code and wordpress.

**Thank You!**: Thanks to anyone who is kind hearted enough to share any ideas. I've been scouring the web for days!

Comment: This question is too broad. You're basically asking for the implementation of an entire system, that's not how it works on SO. But a few hints to get you started. Drop the idea that you have a "master XML file", that's not gonna fly. Simplest, most straight-forward case: You need an SSL certificate, a database (e.g. MySQL), two DB tables (episodes, subscribers), and a server-side scripting languages (e.g. PHP). New episodes go into the `episodes` DB table. When the client requests a file, PHP queries the DB using that user's ID/subscription key and generates the RSS in a `for` loop.

Comment: Ideally, every user has a random, non-gueassable token (such as a GUID) which is saved in the DB, alongside the username in the `subscribers` table. The token should be part of the the URL each episode (e.g. as an URL parameter). Without a valid token, no files are served. This way you're making it hard for non-paying customers to leech your data, although if a paying customer shares their token, you would have no way of knowing.

Comment: All these things lead to much more focused questions - such as *"how to output RSS from PHP"* or *"how to create a MySQL table with an automatic GUID column"*, or *"is a GUID a good idea for this, or should I use something else"* - which are not only a better fit for SO's Q&A format, but also might have been asked before in some form or other, and are already answered.

Comment: Thanks for the great breakdown, Tomalak! You're right, my question was definitely broad, I was just hoping if I outlined the general goal, someone might know a specific tool or solution that already exists. But I know SO is best when you can really be specific, so I appreciate the focus on the database method you've outlined. Your suggested follow up questions are right on, and I have a lot more to seek out and a specific direction for a solution method. Thanks for taking the time.

Comment: Always feel free to come back with a specific question, accompanied by some code, that focuses on one aspect of the issue. I'd say strategy-wise you should start with a PHP script that generates dummy RSS from a hard-coded list of values. (I say PHP because LAMP, i.e. "Linux, Apache, MySQL, PHP" still is the most common technology stack out there, but it could easily be anything else). Then enhance it to get the list of values from the database. Then enhance it to support user IDs/tokens. When that works, integrate it into your payment solution/website.